# Adding to favorite doesn't persist state

Tags: android, favorites

I have a tour list in android and I am trying to implementing add to favorites.
Favorite works for the list that is added in myTours but doesn't work for tours from search list.

This is the code:

```
private List<Tour> tourList;
holder.imgFavourite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(tourList.get(position).getFav().equalsIgnoreCase("0")) {
                   tourList.get(position).setFav("1");
                  //  listener.onFavourited(tourList.get(position), true);
                    holder.imgFavourite.setImageResource(R.drawable.faved);
                } else {
                    tourList.get(position).setFav("0");
                  //  listener.onFavourited(tourList.get(position), false);
                    holder.imgFavourite.setImageResource(R.drawable.not_faved);
                }
            }
        });
```

Here when I click on Fav icon gets changed to faved. But if I search for different category and again come back to that category state doesn't persist.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Provide more code in detail please !!

Comment: You need to use setTag()/getTag()

Comment: @VVB you mean setTag() instead of setFav()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listview/RecyclerView reuses views. If your list has 20 items and 4 are visible at one time, as you scroll, the views are reused to show the new visible views to save memory. So if you alter the view at position 5 and scroll down and scroll back up to position 5, the view that you changed in position 5 is not the same view that you are seeing after you scroll back up. Hence the view changes

To fix this, maintain a global variable in the adapter which stores the favorite position and in the onBindViewHolder, add a condition like

```
if(position = favPosition)
    <Change to fav view>
else
    <Change to Normal View>
```

The else condition is really important or else multiple views will have the Fav view

Comment: But I have a option to add Tour to myTourList. And fav  works fine for that list even if I scroll or change to another tab and come back. It only doesn't work for search list items.

Comment: Also for search items scrolling up and down doesn't loose a state but when I open another tab/view and come back to that view and search similar tour it doesn't persist. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

For recycler view always consider both cases only one case cause your list to change behaviour(like set same image for other list item because it reuses the cell for your view).the below mistake you are doing.
In bindviewholder you are getting data from model class and based on that you set resources for imageview.which is good.
But the problem is there no case for failing of the condition so you are losing the state and if you scroll down and again come to this item you lost your state or face behaviour that goes against your requirement.
So simply provide case for not matching your condition.

Comment: Please see my comments for the above answer. Problem is only for the tours from the search list. It works fine for the myTours list.